Default Helm Templates throw Error: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.labels of type string
I have been trying to deploy a simple image from ACR to AKS using Helm.
The Helm Templates are almost completely fresh out of the command "helm create hello":
Chart.yaml:
apiVersion: v2
name: hello
description: A Helm chart for Kubernetes

# A chart can be either an 'application' or a 'library' chart.
#
# Application charts are a collection of templates that can be packaged into versioned archives
# to be deployed.
#
# Library charts provide useful utilities or functions for the chart developer. They're included as
# a dependency of application charts to inject those utilities and functions into the rendering
# pipeline. Library charts do not define any templates and therefore cannot be deployed.
type: application

# This is the chart version. This version number should be incremented each time you make changes
# to the chart and its templates, including the app version.
# Versions are expected to follow Semantic Versioning (https://semver.org/)
version: 0.1.0

# This is the version number of the application being deployed. This version number should be
# incremented each time you make changes to the application. Versions are not expected to
# follow Semantic Versioning. They should reflect the version the application is using.
# It is recommended to use it with quotes.
appVersion: "1.16.0"

values.yaml:
# Default values for hello.
# This is a YAML-formatted file.
# Declare variables to be passed into your templates.

replicaCount: 1

image:
  repository: containerregistrybootcamp.azurecr.io/hello
  pullPolicy: Always
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: ""

imagePullSecrets: []
nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

serviceAccount:
  # Specifies whether a service account should be created
  create: true
  # Automatically mount a ServiceAccount's API credentials?
  automount: true
  # Annotations to add to the service account
  annotations: {}
  # The name of the service account to use.
  # If not set and create is true, a name is generated using the fullname template
  name: ""

podAnnotations: {}
podLabels: {}

podSecurityContext: {}
  # fsGroup: 2000

securityContext: {}
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  # readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  # runAsNonRoot: true
  # runAsUser: 1000

service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  port: 3000

ingress:
  enabled: false
  className: ""
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: chart-example.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #   cpu: 100m
  #   memory: 128Mi

livenessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http
readinessProbe:
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: http

autoscaling:
  enabled: false
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 100
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 80
  # targetMemoryUtilizationPercentage: 80

# Additional volumes on the output Deployment definition.
volumes: []
# - name: foo
#   secret:
#     secretName: mysecret
#     optional: false

# Additional volumeMounts on the output Deployment definition.
volumeMounts: []
# - name: foo
#   mountPath: "/etc/foo"
#   readOnly: true

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}


Everything else is left totally untouched, for example
deployment.yaml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "hello.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "hello.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "hello.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "hello.labels" . | nindent 8 }}
        {{- with .Values.podLabels }}
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "hello.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            {{- toYaml .Values.livenessProbe | nindent 12 }}
          readinessProbe:
            {{- toYaml .Values.readinessProbe | nindent 12 }}
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          {{- with .Values.volumeMounts }}
          volumeMounts:
            {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.volumes }}
      volumes:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}


My Helm version is v3.14.3+gf03cc04.
I tried stringifying every number.

I've created a new helm chart and changed the files you mentioned in your post but I'm not able to reproduce the error when running helm template command. Helm version is the same as yours.

the deployment is part of a pipeline:
...

task: HelmDeploy@0
inputs:
connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
azureSubscription: 'Azure subscription 1(2)(...xyz...)'
azureResourceGroup: 'BootcampGroup'
kubernetesCluster: 'AksBootcamp'
useClusterAdmin: true
command: 'upgrade'
chartType: 'Name'
chartName: 'hello'
...

the full error message is:
##[error]Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to decode "": json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ObjectMeta.metadata.labels of type string

Can you [edit] the question so it contains a [mcve]?  Do you need, for example, the boilerplate configuration for an Ingress object, or can it be deleted from the question?  What is the definition of the hello.labels template?  Can you also make sure the complete text of the error message is included in your question?

To Clarify:
I built the folder structure with . Changed some parts as you can see above. Everything else is the same. Then I pushed this to an Azure DevOps Repo.
My Azure Pipeline references this repo and should deploy the pods. I have no more error messages.

It seems like Azure DevOps Pipeline has difficulty resolving terms in the form of "{{- include "hello.labels" . | nindent 8 }}".
I ended up create a helm template and hard coding these parts. Then the error vanishes.

When the value starts with a number, in YAML, it will be interpreted as a number. If you have dynamic values that might have hex strings, and if the string itself starts with a number (like 1235abcdf), it will cryptically fail with the above message.
Make sure that, for fields that you're expecting strings, enforce it to be quoted with {{ ... | quote }}
That also means that if you have a dynamically created YAML, you'll need to recursively quote those as well
